# Connect ADB Proxy with UserName and Password

Tags: shell, adb, proxy-authentication

i'm using ADB with command

```
adb shell settings put global http_proxy <ip>:<port>
```

it's works very good .

but i can't login proxy if it had protected with username and password

please help me if you know anything .

Answer (score 5):

I made some investigation and find out correct settings to enable http proxy with authentication via adb:

```
adb shell settings put global http_proxy 192.168.225.100:3128
adb shell settings put global global_http_proxy_host 192.168.225.100
adb shell settings put global global_http_proxy_port 3128
adb shell settings put global global_http_proxy_username foo
adb shell settings put global global_http_proxy_password bar
```

And to disable proxy:

```
adb shell settings delete global http_proxy
adb shell settings delete global global_http_proxy_host
adb shell settings delete global global_http_proxy_port
adb shell settings delete global global_http_proxy_username
adb shell settings delete global global_http_proxy_password
adb shell settings delete global global_http_proxy_exclusion_list
adb shell settings delete global global_proxy_pac_url
adb shell reboot
```

Unfortunately it is not working in my Wear OS wristwatch. May be you'll be more lucky.

Comment: answer works, but for me not. I use an automatic proxy configuration url with user and password needed (.pac) how I set that?

Comment: Quick question, does "with authentication" means it needs authentication or this code can bypass it?