# Setting a proxy using adb

Tags: android, adb

I found these commands to add/remove proxy using ADB:

```
#To Add Proxy
adb shell settings put global http_proxy 192.168.1.252:8080

#To Remove Proxy
adb shell settings put global http_proxy :0
```

Is possible to also add in the `same` command or `another`, the proxy `username` and `password`?

Atm it pops a window asking to input this info, but I would like to also add it using ADB.

Comment: According to the documentation there is only the global proxy hostname and port setting: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global#HTTP_PROXY

Comment: @Robert While googling about i found many places pointing to `global_http_proxy_username`, `global_http_proxy_password`, i tried both, but it still is asking for authentication.

Comment: Have you found a post where a user states that this setting has worked? Another possibility is that these options are only present on certain devices as the manufacturer has added this settings (because I don't find any reference to `global_http_proxy_username, global_http_proxy_password` in Android sources AOSP)..

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried:

Enable http proxy with authentication:

```
adb shell settings put global http_proxy 192.168.225.100:3128
adb shell settings put global global_http_proxy_host 192.168.225.100
adb shell settings put global global_http_proxy_port 3128
adb shell settings put global global_http_proxy_username foo
adb shell settings put global global_http_proxy_password bar
```

And to disable proxy:

```
adb shell settings delete global http_proxy
adb shell settings delete global global_http_proxy_host
adb shell settings delete global global_http_proxy_port
adb shell settings delete global global_http_proxy_username
adb shell settings delete global global_http_proxy_password
adb shell settings delete global global_http_proxy_exclusion_list
adb shell settings delete global global_proxy_pac_url
adb shell reboot
```

Relevant sources:

- [Connect ADB Proxy with UserName and Password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60220603/connect-adb-proxy-with-username-and-password)

Answer (score 1):

An android app that sets the proxy settings for a wifi access point by using adb. This DOES NOT require root and will work with any device that has USB debugging on or any emulator (including Genymotion).

[link](https://github.com/manadream/AndroidProxySetter)

sample

```
adb shell am start -n tk.elevenk.proxysetter/.MainActivity -e host 192.168.56.1 -e port 8080 -e ssid PublicWifi -e bypass test.com,test2.com -e reset-wifi true
```

Comment: What does `-e bypass test.com,test2.com` mean?

Comment: The bypass string to use for proxy settings

Comment: So the websites that we don't want to go through the proxy, you mean?